# a stop after downoading packages during upgrading the system

Tags: upgrade

I am updating the system to 13.10 using terminal. Write now i am in the process of downloading the packages. After downloading the packages can I temporary stop my upgrade, send my computer to sleep and return to updating later without downloading everything again?
Thank you in advance

Comment: AFAIK 13.10 is unsupported. Which version are you currently using? I feel that you are likely to mess with your OS with the upgrade you are doing, because I don't think you are not doing what you think you are doing. Simply put, you shouldn't be upgrading to 13.10, because that shouldn't be possible.

Comment: The question is not in the exact version. I might have confused the number. Just in general in Ubuntu is it possible to do what I have described? I am using 12.04

Answer (score 0):

### CLI way

This should be possible by pausing the upgrade process.

First run the upgrade process

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Now you should be seeing various output. When you wish, pause the command by giving a SIGTSTP signal by pressing the  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> keys.

You should now see something like

```
[1]+  Stopped                 sudo do-release-upgrade
```

You should NOT close the terminal. Now later, as per your wish, you could restart the process by typing

```
fg 1
```

where 1 is the job id that you see while pausing the command.

In case you forgot the job id, you can run

```
jobs
```

which will show you all list of jobs, like this

```
[1]+  Stopped                 sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: I know the GUI way as well but can't guess which process should be paused. Can anyone help?